# Pygame - How do I ensure that a player completes a task in the correct order?

Tags: pygame, nested-if

I'm young (a freshman in high school), so I don't know a lot about Pygame or about coding in general. For my computer science class final project, I'm making a restaurant game similar to Papa's Pizzeria. Right now, I'm just working on the basics, and one function of it is that you need to prepare the food in a certain order or you will get an error message, or get points taken off, etc. For example, if you wanted to prepare a burger, you would have to put the bun, then the burger, then the toppings... You get the idea. It wouldn't work if you put the burger before the bun. How would I accomplish this? I was thinking to use nested if statements. Also, the ingredients are put on the food by pressing the key that corresponds with the ingredient (e.g. "L" for lettuce). The code below shows what I have and hopefully will help you understand what I'm asking. The part I'm having trouble with starts at the first elif statement, I just put the rest for context.

```py
running = True
while running:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(running == False):
            pygame.QUIT()
            sys.exit()
        if(event.type == QUIT):
            running = False
        if(event.type == KEYDOWN):
            if(event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                running = False
            elif(event.key == K_l):
                screen.blit(lettuce, ((counter_width-lettuce_width)/2 + 2, (counter_height-lettuce_height)/2))
                print("lettuce")
                if(event.key == K_a):
                    screen.blit(apple, ((counter_width-apple_width)/2 + 2, (counter_height-apple_height)/2))
                else:
                    print("wrong")
```

As you can see in the code, I put another if statement inside the first elif statement, so after you press the "L" key, it checks if you pressed the "A" key, and if you don't (else statement), it gives you an error message. However, when I press L and press another key afterwards, it gives me the error message regardless of whether I pressed the correct key (if I press L and then A, which is the correct order, it gives me the error message). I know this is because the if statement meant for the A key is still checking for the same key press event as the if statement meant for the L key, so since I pressed L at first the if statement checking for A only detects that. My problem is figuring out what to change so it works as intended. Please don't judge my code or my experience, I am still learning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important thing to understand is that events of type `pygame.KEYDOWN` only represent a single key being pressed down.

The user clicking 'k' and then 'a' in any order will fire off two KEYDOWN events, all of which run your code because of the line `for event in pygame.event.get():`. This is why your code will never recognize that both are being pressed at the same time. (`event.key` cannot be equal to K_l and K_a)

You need to store whether a key is being pressed to accomplish your goal of recognizing when multiple keys are being used.

*Hint: You can use a boolean to store whether a key is pressed*

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # KEYDOWN event for when a key is pressed
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_l:
            l_pressed = True
                print("lettuce")
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            a_pressed = True
            if l_pressed:
                print("tomato")

    # KEYUP event for when a key is released
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            a_pressed = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_l:
            l_pressed = False
```

Edit: did not actually want multiple keys press functionality:

```py
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_l:
                print("lettuce")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                print("tomato")
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that it still registers the first keydown even when I'm trying to check for the second one. I'm not pressing both down at once.

Comment: Okay I added a simpler example that just checks for each individual button, is that what you were asking?

Comment: Thank you! I used the booleans to make sure that each condition was true before moving on to the next ingredient.